# Adding custom field validation to ROR Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I’m trying to configure devise to validate user registration by checking if a code the user inputs at registration exists in a table. To test it out, I'm currently just testing input against a static string. Any thoughts on how to do it? Problem is that string is not being passed from the :ticket_id registration field to the :invite_code_valid function in the user class for some reason. When I check what's in the variable, it's just blank, and using string "hello" when registering gives the error message I specified.

Code is in hero git so I can’t link to it, but I did this:

**Migration:**

```
class AddUserTicketIdField < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
        t.text  :ticket_id
    end
  end
end
```

**In models/user.rb:**

validate :invite_code_valid, :on => :create

```
  def invite_code_valid
    unless self.ticket_id == "hello"
      self.errors.add(:ticket_id, "membership code is not one we recognize, check again?")
    end
  end
```

**In devise/registrations/new.html.erb:**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Membership_code %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :ticket_id, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>
```

To see if the code works at all I tried validating a certain email like this:

```
  def invite_code_valid
    unless self.email == "some@email.com"
      self.errors.add(:ticket_id, "membership code is not one we recognize, check again?")
    end
  end
```

That works. When registering using email some@email.com, registration goes though, but not otherwise.

What is going on, am I missing something about how Devise works?

–––––––––––– SOLVED ––––––––––––

Josh Deedens answer below hit the spot. THANKS! For future reference, this is what I did.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
       devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)        << :ticket_id
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is on you're being bitten by strong_parameters:

From the Devise README: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters:

> When you customize your own views, you may end up adding new attributes to forms. Rails 4 moved the parameter sanitization from the model to the controller, causing Devise to handle this concern at the controller as well.

The docs go on to give this example

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

So try adding the `configure_permitted_parameters` method to your ApplicationController, along with the corresponding filter.   And replace the `:username` key with `:ticket_id` and see if that solves the problem of your ticket_id being nil.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a LOT! That pretty much fixed it! Using the code above of the bat gave a method error for some reason, but I googled around a bit and modified it. Solution in original question! Thanks a million!